# MYSQL Copy field from one table to another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two MYSQL tables.  One is '`orders`' and another is '`users`'.  I just added a field to my '`orders`' table called '`state`'.  I'd like to go through each record in my '`orders`' table and find which state the order will be shipped to, then add that to the '`state`' field.

The '`orders`' table has a '`user`' field that would match the '`id`' field in my '`users`' table.

I know how to do this programmatically with PHP but I'm sure it can be done with a simple SQL statement.  I'm just not terribly great with SQL so this will help me learn.

Comment: Note you run the risk of a user having an address change to a different state and then updating an order to the new address instead of the old one unless you have some date logic in your update.

Comment: Great note.  I'll definitely figure something out to deal with this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE `orders` o
LEFT JOIN `users` u
ON o.user = u.id
SET state = u.state
```

Comment: Maybe better as an inner join, depends on your needs.

Comment: Awesome, this worked great!  All I had to do was change `SET state = u.state` to `SET o.state = u.state`.  Thanks!